# Time lapse Bangkok photography - Exposure?

Tags: timelapse, cityscape

On the first week of October I will be in Bangkok and would like to take time lapse pictures of the city's skyline, let's say every half an hour starting from an hour before sunset (which at that period of year in that location is about 18.05) and ending when the sky is dark (let's say 21.30). The camera will look north-west.
I will try to use a device that lets me take photographs during a time interval by adjusting automatically my camera's exposure time. I have 2 possibilities to do that: linearly and logarithmically. From the specs of the device:

```
By linear, the exposure time is increased or decreased by dividing the 
difference between start exposure time and end exposure time by number of 
photos. On the other hand, the logarithm method increase or
decrease exposure time by dividing the log of difference between start exposure
time and end exposure time and convert it back to numeric value. The linear
method is simple straight forward one, the logarithm method requires some
calculation and experience in estimating start and end exposure time.
```

The device can, of course, do it both ways: increasing and decreasing exposure.

Provided that I would like to minimize the possibility that I'd have to do it with both modes to see what's the best one (I'd need to leave the camera while I go around in the city 2 times in that case - I'd like to avoid that -), which one would you consider using?
How would you set the camera at the beginning to balance as good as possible the brightness of the sky with the darkness of the buildings during the whole process?

Comment: Not really part of your question, but it gets dark really fast in Bangkok.

Comment: Well may not be an answer, but it surely is a good hint

Comment: Just to clarify, you do not wish to use automatic exposure mode?

Comment: That would be a third option, which I'm trying to avoid, since I cannot control very much how the scene is exposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments it gets dark pretty quickly in that part of the world.

Since you've only got one shot at it and you don't know how long sunset will last, I'd suggest you put the camera on a fixed ISO, Aperture priority and matrix metering and let it run.

Initially you will end up with uneven exposures but you also have the best chance of getting the exposure as close to correct as you can in each image and you will also get the actual exposure data from the exif data which you can use to make adjustments in post to compensate.